# error 424 object required error

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, range

I'm trying to input the values in a range of cells into an array.

the following code give me an error 424 object required message. Please help

`feedingtypes() = wbfeedingtypes.Range("A2:A" & lrowfeedingtypes).Value`

Comment: Haven't played with the code yet but just noticed quickly.  Is     'wbfeedingtypes' a workbook or worksheet variable?

Comment: wbfeedingtypes is a workbook. to update you, I had mispelled this in my code, and I fixed it... However, there is still something else wrong with the statement as it gives me a different error : object doesnt support this property or method "error 438"

Comment: I don't use arrays often in excel but I don't think you can just dump an entire range into one.  I'll try something and get back to you

Comment: I also tried the code without `.Value` so it reads
`feedingtypes() = wbfeedingtypes.Range("A2:A" & lrowfeedingtypes)`

Comment: You need a worksheet between the workbook and range, a workbook doesn't contain ranges. Btw, if you want to respond to someone in the comments, you can reply to them by using @ + their username.

Comment: @eirikdaude the workbook has only one worksheet... can you please show me how I can refer to it?

Comment: I think Ralph edited it into his answer, but to answer it here as well, it would be something like `wbfeedingtypes.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & lrowfeedingtypes)`, if you haven't edited the worksheets name, and your language is English.

Comment: Preferably refer to worksheets by number instead of name.  If someone renames the worksheet it will break your code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
Dim feedingtypes() As Variant
feedingtypes = wbfeedingtypes.Sheets(1).Range("A2:A" & lrowfeedingtypes)
```

Note, that there are not brackets in the second line of code after the variable name.
Based on your comments it seems there is only one worksheet. Hence, you can also refer to the sheet by number. I changed the answer accordingly.

Comment: thanks,now with this statement. error 13: runtype mismatch.

Comment: ok this works, I had `Dim feedingtypes() As String`, changed to the `Variant` and it works.

Comment: This code works if I define the dimension as Variant, but not String
But I would like to define the dimension of each value as a string, why can't I do that?

Comment: If you want to use `string` then you have to assign each array item one by one as shown in the solution provided by @iShaymus. If you want to assign them all at once you have to use the type `variant`. I am aware that variant variables are not as fast in their performance as strings would be. But one of Excel's biggest speed constraint is reading from a sheet and (even more so) writing back to a sheet (later on in your code I'd assume).

Answer (score 1):

I have run and tested the following

```
Sub RangeToArray()
  Dim i As Long
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim myRange As Range, cell As Range
  Dim feedingtypes() As String

  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
  Set myRange = ws.Range("A1:A20")
  i = 1

  For Each cell In myRange
    'Only add non blanks
    If cell.Value <> "" Then
      'Resize the array each time another cell is added
      ReDim Preserve feedingtypes(i)
      feedingtypes(i) = cell.Value
      i = i + 1
    End If
  Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: I think that this would definitely work, but I would really like to work around a smaller statement, because the overall code for which I am using this is already very big.

Comment: The reason for this code other than the one liner is that it allows you to control which data to pull out of a range e.g. in my example ignoring blanks.  This many not be required for your purpose but could save you time down the road if you decide to ignore blanks, numeric etc.

Comment: Also you can put it in a module and then just call it. `Call RangeToArray(myWorksheet, myRange)`

Comment: If you have any speed concerns then you might want to read this post: https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/05/25/writing-efficient-vba-udfs-part-1/ The author has (seemingly) spent a significant amount of time to speed-test and refine his code.